# Phonegap advantages and disadvantages

Tags: javascript, android

what is phonegap.what is the advantages of using phonegap.what is the difference between android phonegap and blackberry phonegap.what is the disadvantages of phonegap.

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap is framework to deploy your web based skill to multiple platforms.

Phonegap just executed inside a UIWebView control, and the PhoneGap JavaScript APIs your js calls are routed to native APIs.

Advantages of Phonegap:

- Build your app once with web-standards
- Wrap it with PhoneGap
- Deploy to multiple platforms!

Disadvantages of Phongap :

PhoneGap is effectively a web app within a wrapper, so you're limited to what a web app can do (plus the features added by PhoneGap). It's nearly impossible to get a web app to perform as well as a native app, and there are plenty of little quirks. You're not going to have native controls (you have to fake it for the most part), and things like scrolling behave differently. Overall, the experience of a web app is rarely (if ever) on par with the experience of a native app